# Graph.js does not apply my options setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, ejs

I have tried using lots of suggested things but nothing is working
I am trying to start y-axis from 0 but if there is only one data (one label and one data) it gives value on axis from [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orDGI.png) -1 to 1 Which I am trying to avoid. If there is multiple data [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt1pi.png) still it is not starting from 0

Below jsDelivr I am using
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>`

I have also tried below CDN it did not work
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.min.js`

My frontend is in ejs

Below is the function I am using to create and manipulate chart

```
function updateChart(lables, data, id, datasetLbl) {
    let date = moment();
    date = date.format('YYYY/MM/DD');

    const ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: lables.length < 1 ? [date] : lables, // Assuming each data point has a label
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: datasetLbl,
                    data: !data.length ? [0] : data, // Assuming each data point has a value
                    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                    tension: 0.1,
                },
            ]   ,
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    stepSize: 1
                },
                x: {
                    display: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });
}
```

I have tried lots of things

```
options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    // min: 0,
                    //suggestedMin: 0,
                    ticks:{
                        //here also I have tried to define suggestedMin and min but did not work
                    },
                },
                x: {
                    display: true,
                },
            },
        },
```

Nothing is affecting not stepsize not min every option has no effect on my chart

I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Your issue can't be reproduced. Any one of the three options: `beginAtZero: true`, `min: 0`, OR `suggestedMin: 0` work as expected, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp2n7yk1/). Unrelatedly, unless you declare your x [axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#common-options-to-all-axes) `type: "time"` the values of your dates are not used, they are treated as plain text labels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `suggestedMin`:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
},
```